# python pandasデータフレームで条件から得た値を書き換えるには？その位置情報が分かればできるのだろうが、それがわからない。

Tags: python, pandas

素人質問で申し訳ないです。
pandasデータフレームで条件に当てはまる数値を任意の数値（または文字）に書き換えたい場合どのようにすればよいのでしょうか。

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 0, 2, 1], 'B': [1,2,3,4], 'C' : [5,7,2,5]},index = ["AA","BB","CC","DD"])
print (df)
```

このようなデータフレームから

```
print (max(df.loc['AA','A':'C']))
```

このように指定の”行”（このばあいはAA）ごとに最大値を見つけて、その最大値を任意の文字に書き換えたいのです。（本当のデータフレームには他の列もあるためこのように列の範囲指定しています）

```
max(df.loc['AA','A':'C']) = 100
```

としてもSyntaxError: can't assign to function call
となってしまいできません。

該当値の位置情報がわかれば書き換えれると思うのですが、idxmaxなどを試してもうまくいきません。

この質問のすらうまく書けていないように思いますが、お助けいただけると幸いです。

Comment: `df.loc['AA', df.loc['AA'].idxmax()] = 100` という事ですか？

Comment: 早い回答本当に有難うございました！なるほど、これでできました！
ところで同じことを
    df.iloc[1, df.iloc[1].idxmax()] = 100
で試すとCan only index by location with...というエラーになるのですが、何を間違えているのでしょうか、同じことをしているつもりなのですが、、もしお時間あれば教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: iloc() メソッドではカラムの位置を指定する必要がありますので、`df.iloc[1, df.columns.get_loc(df.iloc[1].idxmax())] = 100` とします。念の為に申し添えて置きますと、インデックス番号は `0` から始まりますので、`AA` の行を操作する場合は `df.iloc[0, df.columns.get_loc(df.iloc[0].idxmax())] = 100` となります。

Comment: @metropolis ご教示いただき誠に有難うございます。大変勉強になります。グーグルで調べ続けていましたが解決できずにいました。本当に助かります。深謝！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

各行の最大値を100に置き換えるということでしょうかね。
とりあえず思いつく方法を何点か

```
# DataFrame.eq() と df.mask() を使う方法
res = df.mask(df.eq(df.max(axis=1),axis=0), 100)
print(res)
#    A    B    C
#AA  0    1  100
#BB  0    2  100
#CC  2  100    2
#DD  1    4  100
```

---

```
# 行毎に関数を適用する方法
res = df.apply(lambda r: r.mask(r==r.max(),100), axis=1)
print(res)
    A    B    C
#AA  0    1  100
#BB  0    2  100
#CC  2  100    2
#DD  1    4  100
```

---

```
# 単純に行毎にループを回して、もとのDataFrameを書き換える方法
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[idx, row==row.max()] = 100
print(df)
#    A    B    C
#AA  0    1  100
#BB  0    2  100
#CC  2  100    2
#DD  1    4  100
```

---

**【追記】**
最大値を求めるColumnを 'A','B','C' に限定する場合

```
# DataFrame.eq() と df.mask() を使う方法
res = df.mask(df.eq(df[['A','B','C']].max(axis=1),axis=0), 100)
```

---

```
# 行毎に関数を適用する方法
res = df.apply(lambda r: r.mask(r==r[['A','B','C']].max(),100), axis=1)
```

---

```
# 単純に行毎にループを回して、もとのDataFrameを書き換える方法
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[idx, row==row[['A','B','C']].max()] = 100
```

Comment: magichanさん ご回答を拝見し、ついつい興奮してしまいました。すばらしいです。分かりやすい解説とそれぞれのアプローチのご教授誠に有難うごじあます。プログラミングは無限大ですね。また勉強が楽しくなりました。お礼申し上げます。

Comment: しかし、、質問内容を分かりやすくつもりでintのみのデータフレームで質問しましたが、実際にはstrを含む列がデータフレームに含まれています。ですから任意の"列範囲’を指定してプログラムを組まないとエラーになって今います。上記応用してがんばってみますが、お時間あればご教示頂けると幸いです。分かりにくくてごめんなさい。

このようなDF
    
`df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 0, 2, 1], 'B': [1,2,3,4], 'C' : [5,7,2,5], 'D' : ["apple","orange","grape","banana"]},index = ["AA","BB","CC","DD"])`

Comment: 最大値を求める列を限定したバージョンを追記しました

Comment: magichanさん ご親切な追記、誠に有難うございました。大変勉強になりましたし、これから勉強すべきことも見えてきたきがします。

Answer (score 2):

最大値が複数ある場合を考慮して、次のコードでどうでしょうか。

```
df1 = df.loc[:,'A':'C']
# 行ごとの最大値を求める
s = df1.max(axis=1)
# 行毎の最大値の位置を見つける(最大値を引けば0)
m = df1.sub(s, axis=0) == 0
# 書き換え
df[m] = 100
```

Comment: Yasuhiroさん 素晴らしいです！質問の先のやろうとしていることがこれだけのコードでできてしまうとは。for loop, interrows()を使わないといけないと思っていたのが、すごくシンプルに処理できそうです！本当にありがとうございます。